# Exclude string in Regex - PCRE format

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-negation

I am trying to exclude `OT:100000/GMT-04` from the complete text i.e `established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond...,OT:100000/GMT-04,Suppressed=3`

Can anyone please help with **PCRE** format regex for it.

I tried `.+(?<p>\w{2}\:\d{6}\/\w{3}\-\d{2}).+` but I think it isn't the correct one.

I am testing in on www.regex101.com, **PCRE format**.

Comment: What about using a "replace to blank" on that string? That would seem to be the easiest approach. Like the following example in JavaScript: `str.replace('OT:100000/GMT-04','')`.

Comment: Is it equivalent to everything between the last two commas?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: I writing it in PCRE format and testing it directly in Regex101.com.

Comment: Please check this - https://regex101.com/r/USPFPU/1

Comment: @Toto: I have mentioned PCRE in my earlier post, please check.

Comment: [Is that what you want](https://regex101.com/r/USPFPU/2)?

Comment: Thanks @Toto, yes but I want to exclude 'OT:100037/GMT-04' from the selection in way that only 'established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond...,'  and ',Suppressed=3' should be visible as one selection.

Comment: This is not possible with regex. A group contains only **consecutive** characters. Here you have 2 groups.

Comment: @Toto - Yes, understood. So, now I am planning to replace the middle section with blank spaces. I think that should be under match condition, trying it on my end.

Answer (score -1):

You have to replace the part with a blank word. As you haven't described the language, I am including method in several languages:

## Javascript

```
var str = "The string";
str.replace("OT:100000/GMT-04", "");
```

## CSharp

```
String str = "The string";
Console.WriteLine(str.replace("OT:100000/GMT-04", ""));
```

Comment: Thanks Wasif, I mentioned the `**REGEX format is PCRE - (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions**`

Comment: Just use the method of replacing on perl